# Save pdf attachment using a field from the pdf

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

The code below finds my `Subfolder` from my Inbox then opens the email in the active window.

I would like to **`"Open"`** the `pdf` form attached to this email so I could save the attachment using one of the text fields from the `pdf` form.

The only code I can find saves the attachment to the temp folder but does not get the content from the `pdf` form.

```
Sub OpenMailAttachment()

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder 
    Dim openMsg As Outlook.MailItem    
    Dim mySubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim FileName As String    
    Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set mySubFolder = Inbox.Folders("PdfTest")

    mySubFolder.Display

    Set openMsg = mySubFolder.Items(1)

    openMsg.Display

    mySubFolder.Application.ActiveExplorer.Close

    openMsg.Application.ActiveWindow  

    For Each myAttachment in Item.Attachment 
        FileName = "C:\temp\" & myAttachment.FileName

        myAttachment.SaveAsFile FileName

        myAttachment = openMsg.Attachments.Item.DisplayName 
        '(I get Compile error: *.Item* argument not optional)

        myAttachments.Application.ActiveInspector.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

***This should it...***

```
Option Explicit
' use  Declare PtrSafe Function with 64-bit Outlook
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hwnd As Long, _
  ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, _
  ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
  ByVal nShowCmd As Long _
) As Long

Sub OpenMailAttachment()
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim openMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim mySubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Attachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim sFileType As String

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set mySubFolder = Inbox.Folders("PdfTest")

    mySubFolder.Display

    Set openMsg = mySubFolder.Items(1)

    openMsg.Display
    mySubFolder.Application.ActiveExplorer.Close
    openMsg.Application.ActiveWindow

    Set myAttachments = openMsg.Attachments

    If myAttachments.Count Then
        For Each Attachment In myAttachments
            'Last 4 Characters in a Filename
            sFileType = LCase$(Right$(Attachment.FileName, 4))

            Select Case sFileType
                ' Add additional file types below
                Case ".pdf" ', ".doc", "docx", ".xls"

                FileName = "C:\temp\" & Attachment.FileName
                Attachment.SaveAsFile FileName
                ShellExecute 0, "open", FileName, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0
            End Select
        Next
    End If


End Sub
```

***[Option Explicit Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)***

> *<sub>Setting Option Explicit to Off is generally not a good practice. You could misspell a variable name in one or more locations, which would cause unexpected results when the program is run.</sub>*

Comment: The does open the pdf but keeps shutting down my outlook. Error message: MS Outlook has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.

Comment: @CPmngr Which Outlook version are you running?