# Problem converting 32 bit VBA to 64 bit VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Option Base 1

Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlen Lib "kernal32" Alias "lstrlenW" ( _
    ByVal lpString As Long) As LongPtr
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function StrTrim Lib "shlwapi" Alias "StrTrimW" ( _
    ByVal pszSource As Long, _
    ByVal pszTrimChars As Long) As LongPtr
    
Private Function TrimWS(ByVal Text As String) As String
    'unicode safe
    Dim WHITE_SPACE As String
    WHITE_SPACE = " " & vbTab & vbCr & vbLf & Chr(1) & Chr(2) & Chr(3) & Chr(4) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & Chr(7) & Chr(8) & Chr(9) & Chr(10) & Chr(11) & Chr(12) & Chr(13) & Chr(14) & Chr(15) & Chr(16) & Chr(17) & Chr(18) & Chr(19) & Chr(20) & Chr(21) & Chr(22) & Chr(23) & Chr(24) & Chr(25) & Chr(26) & Chr(27) & Chr(28) & Chr(29) & Chr(30) & Chr(31) & Chr(32) & ChrW(&HA0)

    If StrTrim(StrPtr(Text), StrPtr(WHITE_SPACE)) Then
        TrimWS = Left$(Text, lstrlen(StrPtr(Text)))
    Else
        TrimWS = Text
    End If

End Function
```

This function above isn't working when I swapped to 64 bit. The "StrPtr" areas seem to error out because this doesn't exist in 64 bit. Also the lstrlen doesn't seem to work either. It gives a mismatch error.

Can anyone give some suggestions on how to convert this to 64 bit?

I tried swapping the original function to LongPtr, I'm not sure what this function does but it's taking all those charcodes and testing for it. If it exists its running the lstrlen function.

I kinda hit a wall on this one.

Comment: Changing `StrPtr` to [`LongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type) should be the appropriate option, but knowing where you changed `Long` to `LongPtr` would also be important.

Comment: I changed Long to LongPtr only in the function declarations at the top

Comment: I swapped all the functions declaration Long values to LongPtr and I get a type mismatch at lstrlen when I run a sub with a random string.

Comment: Isn't the name of the library *"kernel32"*?

Comment: Yeah I swapped it, looks like I still get a mismatch on lstrlen, the way it works on my 32 bit is, it essentially looks for any of those white spaces, then removes them from the string, all those charcodes and the vbTab etc. Then returns the string without those items.

Comment: `Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenA Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long` is used [here](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=api-pointer-convert-vba-string-ansi-unicode) if that's of any help i.e. swap `Long` and `LongPtr`. Just replace the A with W for Unicode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531822/4539709

Answer (score 2):

I setup the LongPtr in the wrong spot. It works fine now.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlen Lib "Kernel32" Alias "lstrlenW" ( _
    ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function StrTrim Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "StrTrimW" ( _
    ByVal pszSource As LongPtr, _
    ByVal pszTrimChars As LongPtr) As Long
```